# How do you calculate Pr(A | B, C, D, E) if you know Pr( A ∩ B ∩ C ∩ D ∩ E) and Pr(B ∩ C ∩ D ∩ E)?

Tags: probability

all!

Excuse me if the question sounds naive. I have searched on the Web but could not find the answer.

I have studied Chain Rule in my textbook as well as on the Web and understand the basics of it. And I see that it's very useful to calculate the probability of intersection of events when we're given conditional probabilities.

However, if I need to calculate Pr(A | B, C, D, E) and am able to calculate the probabilities Pr( A ∩ B ∩ C ∩ D ∩ E) and Pr(B ∩ C ∩ D ∩ E), can I simply divide the former by the latter? Here, A, B, C, D, and E are all events on the same sample space with non-zero probabilities.

If not, why not? And how to use the Chain Rule in such a case?

Many thanks for answering such a basic question.

Regards,

Quester.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to calculate $P(A\mid B,C,D,E)$ which is just another notation for $P(A\mid B\cap C\cap D\cap E)$, then your proposed calculation is merely using the *definition* of the conditional probability of $A$ given that $B, C, D, E$ all occurred.  The chain rule, on the other hand, says that $$P(A\cap B\cap C\cap D\cap E) = P(E)P(D\mid E)P(C\mid D,E)P(B\mid C,D,E)P(A\mid B,C,D,E),$$ that is, we *use* the conditional probability to find the *unconditional* probability that all the events occurred, not the other way around.
The chain rule can be "justified" as saying that in order for $A,B,C,D,E$ all
to occur, we must assume that $E$ occurred (which has probability $P(E)$), and 
having assumed that, we also need to assume that $D$ occurred which has
probability not $P(D)$ but rather $P(D\mid E)$ since we have already assumed
that $E$ occurred; and then we need to assume that $C$ occurred for which we
use the conditional probability $P(C\mid D,E) = P(C\mid D\cap E)$, and so on.
Note that the first multiplication on the right gives
$$P(E)P(D\mid E) = P(E) \frac{P(D\cap E)}{P(E)} = P(D\cap E)$$
and so the next one gives
$$P(D\cap E)P(C\mid D\cap E) = P(D\cap E)\frac{P(C\cap (D\cap E))}{P(D\cap E)}
= P(C\cap (D\cap E))$$
Do you see a pattern emerging?

Comment: Thanks a tonne for the thorough and elaborate explanation. I completely get what you mean. But my question is that if I know Pr( A ∩ B ∩ C ∩ D ∩ E) and Pr(B ∩ C ∩ D ∩ E), it is correct to obtain P(A∣B,C,D,E) by dividing the former by the latter, right?

Comment: Yes, by _definition_, $$P(A\mid F) = \frac{P(A\cap F)}{P(F)}$$ and all you need to do is write $B\cap C\cap D\cap E$ wherever you see $F$ in the definition. Then, carry out the indicated division using the values of $P(A\cap B\cap C\cap D\cap E)$ and $P(B\cap C\cap D\cap E)$ that you already know.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was perhaps needlessly confusing the two concepts. Many thanks for all your help.